# Como organizar arrays

Tags: php, array, estilo-de-codificação

Na documentação do [Pear](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.arrays.php), ele define um padrão para como montar a estrutura de um array:

```
$some_array = array(
    'foo'  => 'bar',
    'spam' => 'ham',
);
```

Dessa forma, que já utilizo, separa de forma legível os elementos, mas e quanto a um *array* com digamos, 100 elementos. O código ficará muito extenso, mesmo assim está correto?

Esse é o único padrão a seguir? Há outras indicações de como essa estrutura deve ser organizada?

Comment: Com 100 elementos seria uma boa guardar isso no banco de dados.

Comment: Foi apenas uma suposição, @rray. Mas digamos que seja um array contendo configurações a serem salvas ou manipuladas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não, é a mesma coisa. Não tem como fazer mais organizado que isto a não se que exista alguma situação específica que ajude. Você pode pular uma linha para separar blocos que façam sentido, ou pode reavaliar se precisa todos elementos juntos no *array*, depende da situação.

Enfim, é gosto. Este é um padrão bom mas o importante é ser legível, pior seria espremer tudo porque tem informação demais.

Se faz sentido por no código, coloque no código. Só deixe fora do código se houver um motivo para isto. Se as informações devem vir de fonte externa porque o requisito pede isto, seja para facilitar a manutenção, configuração, etc. aí não importa porque os dados serão carregados no *array* sem precisar se preocupar com a sintaxe ficar grande e confusa.